# Genymotion Android Emulator won't work

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I have problems with Genymotion as well. First I had to configure the virtual box DHCP according to the first round of error messages. 
I updated the DHCP

Adapter

IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
   IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.0.0

DHCP Server
   Server Address: 192.168.56.100
   Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
   Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.1
   Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254 // I then updated this to 192.168.56.1

Either way I get this message

> Unable to connect to the virtual device. Genymotion will now close.
>   Please check VirtualBox network configuration.
>
> For more information please refer to:
>   https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

Answer (score 1):

**I have the same problem and i solved it.** 
Actually the problem is on graphic video driver, so update your graphic video driver to latest version.(download the graphic video driver and install then try again. genymotion will run with no problem).

Comment: can you be more specific? "graphic video driver"

Comment: "graphic video driver" is the driver software for the laptops or desktop for optimizing the performance for graphic and video relating works.
Simply search for graphic video driver for your device. For example i have "dell laptop 1569" now search for "dell laptop 1569 graphic video driver software" in google.

Answer (score 0):

on the dhcp-server tab
set the server addres to 192.168.56.1
set lower addres bound to 192.168.56.10 or so
upper addres bound to 192.168.56.254

on the adapter tab
set ipv4 in between lower addres bound and upper addres bound